# Missing .data from element

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm using cdk drag and drop for angular in my web page, but when I'm trying to move one item from one list to another, the function that appears in angular documentation for drag and drop doesn't work.

The function is this one:

```
<code>drop(event) {
if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
  moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
} else {
  transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex);
}
```

}

The thing is that `event.previousContainer` and `event.container` doesn't have the data block, as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Djkl.jpg). I took the function for angular docs, so I think I'm missing something. I will appreciate some help, thanks guys

Comment: Reproduce the issue on stackblitz and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Without HTML code it's hard to say, but I had the same problem and this question has same issue, but more complex & with answer that solved mine: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053126/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-in-angular-7-drag-an